Fixed-point iteration and backwards Euler's method
I have just started with numeric methods for differential equations and have come across this exercise:
We have $f$ which is Lipschitz-continuous in the second argument with constant $L$ and we are looking at the backwards Euler's method: $y_{k+1} = y_k + h_k f(x_{k+1}, y_{k+1})$.
Now define the fixed point iteration $v_{k+1} = y_k + h_k f(x_{k+1}, v_k)$ with an arbitrary value for $v_0$.
It has to be shown that this fixed-point iteration converges to $y_{k+1}$ if we choose $h_k < \frac{1}{L}$.
I don't know where to start. Help is appreciated.
Edit: Why do we need $h_k < \frac{1}{L}$? Why wouldn't $h_k = \frac{1}{L}$ suffice?

Check if the resulting map $\phi(y) = y_k + h_k f(x_{k+1},y)$ is a contraction. This is pretty much immediate. Choosing $h_k = {1 \over L}$ would not necessarily result in a contraction.

@copper.hat Thanks for the answer. All of this is still very new for me. Why is showing that $\phi$ is a contraction enough?

Then the iteration $v_{k+1} = \phi(v_k)$ converges to a unique fixed point (assuming that $\phi$ is defined everywhere). (Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem)
